# Multiple properties with the same type in a structure concept

Tags: bixby

So it appears a structure concept cannot have properties with the same type.

For example if I have the following

```
structure (A) {
  description (blah blah)
  property (prop1) {
    type (Type1)
  }
  property (prop2) {
    type (Type1)
  }
}
```

I get "ERROR: property #prop1 duplicates the type of property #prop2". Am I doing something wrong or is that how it is supposed to work? I don't understand why a structure can't have two properties of the same type. Anyway I have gotten around this by making an additional concept that extends the original, so the types technically have a different name but are functionally the same. However this is kind of a PITA because now I have to make all these extra concepts whenever I need a structure that needs more than one property of the same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending upon your use case, using role-of may be appropriate. What role-of is for is different contexts with the same underlying data.

For instance in a train schedule capsule, I may have an identical list of departure and arrival stations (as an enum). However these are contextually different. Using role-of lets me create a common train station concept but two contextually different roles e.g. both a departure station and an arrival station concept

With role-of I can use both in a structured concept.

Some example code (From my open source Bixby sample code - https://github.com/rogerkibbe/bixby_bart_commuter)

Excerpt from Station.model.bxb - base for station

```
enum (Station) {
  description (BART Station Names)
  symbol(12th St. Oakland City Center)
  symbol(16th St. Mission)
  symbol(19th St. Oakland)
  symbol(24th St. Mission)
  symbol(Antioch)
```

From this, I create two role-of concepts:

```
enum (SearchDepartureStation) {
  description (Train Departure Station)
  features {
    transient
  }
  role-of (Station)
}

enum (SearchArrivalStation) {
  description (Train Arrival Station)
  features {
    transient
  }
  role-of (Station)
}
```

And finally I can use both of the above in a structured concept (excerpt below):

```
structure (TrainSchedule) {
  description (Train Schedule)
  property (searchDepartureStation) {
    type (SearchDepartureStation)
    min (Required)
    max (One)
  }
  property (searchArrivalStation) {
    type (SearchArrivalStation)
    min (Required)
    max (One)
  }
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation, I see that using `role-of` is basically the same as `extends` except you can't add/change properties (which is exactly what I'm looking for). So I think I'll use this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need to have a different type for each property since Bixby uses the type of each property for context when parsing user utterances.

If your Structure would make sense with all the properties of the same type lumped into one, you can use `max(Many)`([documentation](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/structure.property.max)) to indicate that `prop` is of type `Type1` and may contain multiple values. An example use case for this option is a capsule that needs to handle recipe ingredients. All ingredients can be aggregated into one `ingredients` property without needing to have a separate property for each one.

If your Structure requires each property to be separate, you would need to create a different `type` for each property to allow Bixby to differentiate between each property. An example use case for this option is a capsule that tracks sports statistics. It is not enough to label each player on a basketball team as `type(Player)`. You would need to define the type of player as well. This would be done by creating a `Player` type and extending it to each type of player (This is what you have done currently).